# removing url string using jquery

Tags: jquery, attr

Basic I know, but how would / can you remove a url string using jquery?

Say for example, you use `attr` to atribute the image's url string to a div called #picbox, how would you remove the first url string (say on the click function) and then re-attribute the second url string to the div?

```
var urlString1 = "images/1.jpg";
var urlString2 = "images/2.jpg";

$("#picbox").attr('src', urlString1);

$("#changeString").click(function(){
  // remove urlString1 then replace with urlString2
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to remove it. Setting a new `src` will automatically remove the old one:

```
$("#picbox").attr('src', urlString1);

$("#changeString").click(function(){
    $("#picbox").attr('src', urlString2);
});
```

---

For better performance, you should cache that selector:

```
$img = $("#picbox").attr('src', urlString1);

$("#changeString").click(function(){
     $img.attr('src', urlString2);
});
```

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics - The question is pretty vague. As long as the OP does not clarify their intent, I'm assuming this is what they meant.

Comment: I myself meant to answer with a data-* attribute value myself but the question really asks how to remove an attribute in the code comment. I still agree it's vague.

Comment: Thanks @JosephSilber for your comment and solution.  I was simply looking to replace one url string for another.  My apologies if the question was vague but in the past I've had stick from other members for not being concise enough!

Comment: @user1563944 - Can you post the HTML code? [Only the relevant parts](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Don't worry @JosephSilber your solution seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve and there is a mistake in the third line of your code.

```
$("#picbox").attr(urlString1); // tries to read attribute named "images/1.jpg" of #picbox
```

I'm assuming you want something like this:

```
$("#picbox").attr("data-url", urlString1); // stores value "images/1.jpg" in "data-url" attribute

$("#changeString").click(function(event) {
    $("#picbox").attr("data-url", urlString2); // replace previous value with new
});
```

You can replace the attribute name "data-url" with what's suitable for your case. Also, if you keep using data attributes you can use:

```
$("#picbox").data("url", urlString1);
```

to achieve the same as with .attr()

Comment: Thanks @Floremin for your comment.  I'll try using .data() instead of attr() in future.  I've made the correction on my original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlString1 = "images/1.jpg";
var urlString2 = "images/2.jpg";

$("#picbox").attr("src",urlString1);

$("#changeString").click(function(){
  // remove urlString1 then replace with urlString2
  $("#picbox").attr("src",urlString2);
});
```